# How to update SQLite3 database after adding object to a Class?

Tags: django

I just added the `num` object, and tried adding it to my admin, but I get the following error: `Exception Value:

no such column: game_riddle.num`

Here is the class:

```
class Riddle(models.Model):
"""represents a riddle, comprising a question and hints"""
world = models.ForeignKey(World)
question = models.TextField()
num = models.IntegerField()
```

I have a small database and the last time I added the object I had to run:`sqlclear` and then `syncdb`

How can I fix my bug without clearing the database?

Comment: but I dont want to clear or drop tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read this documention: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/installation.html
2. easy_install South
3. After install, put '**south**' in your installed_app in settings
4. Don't forget to sync: **python manage.py syncdb**
5. Run this command: **python manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto**
6. The migrate: **python manage.py migrate**

That's it. Next if you add new model or have changes. Just do step 5 and 6 and your model will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a migration tool such as [South](http://south.readthedocs.org):

> South brings migrations to Django applications. Its main objectives
>   are to provide a simple, stable and database-independent migration
>   layer to prevent all the hassle schema changes over time bring to your
>   Django applications.